# wordpress: Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_wp_error() in wp-includes/load.php on line 339

Tags: php, wordpress

I had my blog on live server it worked fine with my old site, I made backup of that blog folder and after upload new site I also upload that blog folder with out any change in any file but if I try to access my blog page browser shows that:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function is_wp_error() in
>   /home/content/i/m/r/imranskh/html/blog/wp-includes/load.php
>   on line 339

I googled but no clear solution found.

Comment: @ Andrewk : which type of info you require? It is complete issue my friend..

Comment: wordpress: Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_wp_error() in wp-includes/load.php on line 339

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reinstall WP and then insert wp_posts (old table backup) into new new table.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know the site address and the version of WP you're running and what host your using, but your problem is with the MySQL database (and what language the site is in)

Line 339 of load.php is an error check for the MySQL database table prefix.

You said you moved the "files" but how did you migrate the MySQL database between sites?

Go look in your wpconfig.php and see what the table prefix is set to (find the line starting: $table_prefix = 'something here' )

See that that 'something here' prefix matches your actual MySQL database prefix (check that with a PHPMyAdmin or a SQL client).

Some shared hosts will change this table prefix automatically be unique if you use a simple script installer for WordPress.  Did you use an installer to setup WordPress and your MySQL database, or did you do it manually?

Comment: Yes in wp-config.php I found $table_prefix = 'wp_'; and the live mysql db also contains 'wp_' prefix

Comment: You're still not giving us much to go on. Site Address? WP Version? Hosting Environment (PHP Version installed, MySQL version installed)? How exactly did you install WordPres in the new location?  Honestly if it were me I'd redo the install and recreate the database from scratch, see if it's working at defaults, THEN reimport your SQL data and you /wp-content.  It sounds like you may not of migrated correctly.