# After Updating wordpress theme error is coming

Tags: wordpress

This error is coming: Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_wp_error() in /home/mrsjdcom/himalayantraders.in/wp-includes/load.php on line 401 how to resolve it?

When I go to cpanel code showing is
if ( is_wp_error( $prefix ) ) {
        wp_load_translations_early();
        wp_die(
            /* translators: 1: $table_prefix 2: wp-config.php */
            sprintf( __( '**ERROR**: %1$s in %2$s can only contain numbers, letters, and underscores.' ),
                '`$table_prefix`',
                '`wp-config.php`'

Please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have read [ask]? Have you googled that error - see [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-errror-after-updating-to-4-7/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582486/wordpress-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-is-wp-error-in-wp-includes) - looks like it is something wrong with your installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload load.php file manually through FTP and check. Might be a chance of incomplete update.

Comment: When we autoupdate WP, I faced an issue with wp-load.php file few times. I would like to recommend to download copy of same WP version, and replace wp-includes/load.php file on server with one from latest downloaded copy.